# Qual o erro no meu código?

Tags: javascript, variáveis, if, else

Eu queria criar um sistema que perguntasse a nacionalidade do usuário e caso ele respondesse `"Brasileiro"`, o `if` o levaria para uma resposta. Caso qualquer outra nacionalidade, o `else` o levaria para outra, pelo menos esse era meu objetivo. Porém, a mensagem não aparece.

Sabem como podem me ajudar?

```js
function clica() {
    var r = window.document.getElementById('nac')
    var r1 = window.document.getElementById('div#res')
    var r2 = (r.value)
    if (r2 == 'Brasileiro') {
        r1.innerHTML = `Olá, você é ${r}, certo?`
    } else {
        r1.innerHTML = 'Hi, what language do you speak?'
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sistema de Identificação de Nacionalidade</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: grey;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>SISTEMA DE IDENTIFICAÇÃO</h1>
    Qual sua nacionalidade? <input type="text" id="nac">
    <input type="button" value="Clique" onclick="clica()">
    <div id='res'>RESULTADO:</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Como o Javascript é "Case Sensitive" você logo terá problemas se alguém colocar "brasileiro" ou "BRASILEIRO" (maiusculas / minusculas e etc) então no "if r2" coloque "if (r2.toLowerCase() == 'brasileiro')".  A função toLowerCase transforma tudo em minusculo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você der um F12 e observar aba Console do navegador vai ver que seu código está dando o seguinte erro.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

Tente pegar os valores dessa forma

```
var r = window.document.getElementById('nac')
var r1 = window.document.getElementById('res')
```

Não está relacionado a questão, mas sugiro que use assim na sua resposta para quando for brasileiro

```
r1.innerHTML = "Olá, você é "+r2+", certo?"
```

Answer (score 4):

Em seu código, você está usando a função [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), desta forma deve-se usar o id dos elemento para acessa-los via javascript, basta alterar esta linha para usar o id do elemento `'res'`:

```
 var r1 = window.document.getElementById('res')
```

O elemento com `id = div#res` não existe em seu html.

Também modificar como é exibida a mensagem dentro do `comando condicional if` script html.

```
r1.innerHTML = `Olá, você é ${r2}, certo?`
```

Não está na questão mas eu recomendaria utilizar a [igualdade estrita](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) (`===`):

```
 if (r2 === 'Brasileiro') {
```