# Dúvida principiante em javascript condições

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber qual o erro no código, creio que seja nas condições, mas não sei.

Obrigado desde já!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, descreva o que o código deveria fazer e não coloque código como imagem; a plataforma tem suporte para códigos.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Qual o erro no meu código?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/490926/qual-o-erro-no-meu-c%c3%b3digo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para encontrar o elemento de input com o valor desejado deveria buscar por `"input#country"` e você está buscando por `"input#pais"`. O elemento de ID "pais" não existe no código da imagem que colocou na pergunta.

Durante o resgate do elemento de `input` que possui o valor que deseja verificar, você está verificando o **elemento contra a `string` Brasil**. O correto seria, para ambos os casos:

```
var country = document.querySelector("input#country")
```

E na condição, verifique **o valor do elemento**:

```
if (country.value === "Brasil") {
```

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.